# How do I detect any uppercase letter in an Excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I find if any letter in a cell is uppercase, for example to identify proper nouns in a word list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `=NOT(EXACT(LOWER(A1),A1))`, replacing A1 with your cell reference. This allows you to check multiple rows at once.

Comment: ...did you just ask and answer your own question within the same minute?

Comment: Yes - you can do that via "answer your own question, q&a style". I do this when I have something useful I think people would benefit from. Someone's always surprised.

Comment: @SteveTaylor See [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)